# Match cells in two tables while not using foregin key

Tags: mysql

I hope the title best matches my intention.

Here is my setup

**TABLE Customers**

```
*---------------------------------------*
|c_id|f_name |l_name | carrier| referral|
|  1 | Jane  | Doe   | AT&T   | Google  |
|  2 | James | Kahn  | Sprint | Repeat  |
|  3 | Jim   | Flores| Verizon| Walk-in |
*---------------------------------------*
```

**TABLE Carriers**

```
*----------------*
|car_id|car_name |
|  1   | AT&T    |
|  2   | T-Mobile|
|  3   | Verizon |
|  4   | Sprint  |
*----------------*
```

**TABLE Results**

```
*---------------------------------------*
|c_id|f_name |l_name | carrier| referral|
|  1 | Jane  | Doe   |    1   | Google  |
|  2 | James | Kahn  |    4   | Repeat  |
|  3 | Jim   | Flores|    3   | Walk-in |
*---------------------------------------*
```

This is my dilemma. When the customers information is entered from the 'Front-end' it comes into the customers table with the carrier name and not the Foreign Key. How can i setup my query so that it displays with the carrier name from the carrier table and not the customer's table carrier column.

This is what I tried but it doesn't populate when I enter this into my query.

```
$sql = "SELECT f_name, l_name car_name, referral FROM customers JOIN carriers ";
$sql .="ON customers ON customers.carrier = carriers.car_id ORDER BY c_id DESC";
```

I understand this sounds useless since the data I want displayed is already being displayed. However, when the data in this table is manipulated later on in my projects process, the foreign key is used and displays properly. The hang up is when the data firsts arrives into the Results Table.  I was looking and using REGEXP but not sure exactly how to use this.

Comment: what is this results table?

Comment: This is not a DB table but rather an HTML echo table which displays the results. Not sure if this helped answer your question.

Comment: Well your results table is how it should be stored in the database and customers table is how it should be displayed!

Comment: Thank you for the obvious. However, due to the inability to modify the 'Front-End' where the customer data is received and inserted into the DB I need to manipulate the data on the 'Back-End'.

Comment: Well you seemed to have missed the obvious if I may say so, The first step in your current asignment should be to sort out the problem in your database. Please add a carrier_id column to the custom table and then drop the carrier column. then you can start thinking about processing it (which is actually quite easy when you ahve the right desig)

Comment: I partially agree with your comments. But why would I need to add a carrier_id column in the customer table and drop the carrier column when I can keep the same column but instead of the text it would show the matching foreign key from the carriers table. I have a query setup as the data gets manipulated so that if the $carrier matches either the carrier_id or carrier_name it will change the value to the foreign key.

Comment: I recommend that you read up on database normalization

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
select * from Customers c1 inner join Carriers c2 where c1.carrier = c2.car_name
```

Comment: This was helpful. Thank you.

Comment: How could I setup this query to join another table similar to carriers? For sake of arguement call it referrals table.